# Unable to extract links from a google search using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to extract the links that comes on a page after a google search,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('div', class_='r')
```

but it gives me empty list `[]`

Is there a way in which this can be achieved?

Comment: There are no divs in the document with class as ```'r'```. Which class do you want to extract? If you just want all divs, remove class_ argument in find_all call

Comment: I want to extract the links of results that has appeared. (there are 9 search result set which has appeared)

Comment: Looks like the links are asynchronously loaded. Hence in the initial response the links are not available.

Comment: The only solution is to use selenium driver to load webpages and then extract them.

Comment: Even tried with `selenium` using this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("///*[@id='rso']/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite/text()")` but his throws `InvalidSelectorException` error

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using selenium you should get the expected output.Its working with me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path of the chrome driver")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.r')))
for ele in elements:
  print(ele.find_element_by_xpath("./a").get_attribute('href'))
```

Output:

```
https://www.expertsystem.com/machine-learning-definition/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-5-best-programming-languages-for-artificial-intelligence-field/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-machine-learning-and-artificial-intelligence/
http://ai.stanford.edu/~zayd/why-is-machine-learning-hard.html
https://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning
https://www.sas.com/en_gb/insights/analytics/machine-learning.html
https://medium.com/machine-learning-for-humans/why-machine-learning-matters-6164faf1df12
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning
https://www.expertsystem.com/machine-learning-definition/
https://searchenterpriseai.techtarget.com/definition/machine-learning-ML
https://emerj.com/ai-glossary-terms/what-is-machine-learning/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/machine-learning/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

search = input("Search:")
results = 100 # valid options 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, and 100
page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links :
    link_href = link.get('href')
    if "url?q=" in link_href and not "webcache" in link_href:
        print(link.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need in `selenium` as [KunduK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57219519/15164646) suggested, or making things that complicated as [Manali Kagathara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57219968/15164646) suggested for such task.

The problem is because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified thus Google blocks a request and you received a completely different HTML with different selectors since the [default `requests` `user-agent` is `python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). Learn more about [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

Extracting links is as easy as:

```py
# container with needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  # extracting links from container and grabbing href attribute
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "fus ro dah",  # query
  "hl": "en",         # language
  "num": "10"         # number of results
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

-----
'''
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs
https://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Skyrim-Fus-Ro-Dah/00001000-b646-c203-c05e-7534425307e6
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this by using [Google Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a  paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that extracting and bypass from blocks part is already done for the end-user and all that really needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and grab the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "fus ro dah",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])

-------
'''
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah
https://www.etsy.com/market/fus_ro_dah
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs
https://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Skyrim-Fus-Ro-Dah/00001000-b646-c203-c05e-7534425307e6
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.